# Is it possible to turn off the screen without stopping foreground activity?

Tags: screen

Let's suppose I'm playing an idle game where things inside only happen when the game is running in foreground, or listening to music on YouTube, which also must be running in foreground to work. But when the screen is locked (turned off), all foreground activity gets suspended. Is there a way (like some 3rd party software) to somehow just turn off the screen (maybe even without locking the touch surface functioning) so that it wouldn't drain power and the foreground app would still work?

Comment: Exclude the app from Doze (battery optimization).

Comment: automation apps might help to create such action on long-press

Comment: turning the screen brightness down is already a step in that direction, and there are apps that can dim the brightness further afaik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off screen without affecting anything else?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/how-to-turn-off-screen-without-affecting-anything-else)